Wrapping Markdown with a SingleChildScrollView causes flutter layout to fail
When a Markdown widget is placed in a SingleChildScrollView:
  child = SingleChildScrollView(child: child);  // Fails when added

then the layout throws and exception. I'm guessing the Markdown widget doesn't report its height?
Wrapping in:
child = SizedBox(height:350, child: child);

helps but is not a useful solution (since the markdown content determines the height).
I read that some widgets need  to be wrapped in IntrinsicHeight. This doesn't seem to help.
How to fix?
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_markdown/flutter_markdown.dart';

Widget makeMarkdown(BuildContext context) {
  Widget child = Markdown(
    // controller: controller,
    // selectable: true,
    data: """Markdown
* First item
* Second item
* Third item

1. First item
1. Second item
1. Third item
""",
  );
  // child = IntrinsicHeight(child: child);  Does not help
  return child;
}

Widget builder(BuildContext context) {
  Widget child = makeMarkdown(context);
  child = SingleChildScrollView(child: child);  // Fails when added
  // child = IntrinsicHeight(child: child);  Does not help
  return child;
}

Widget mainWidget() {
  return MaterialApp(
      // debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
    body: Builder(builder: builder),
  ));
}

void main() {
  runApp(mainWidget());
}


Markdown is already a ListView, no need to wrap it inside SingleChildScrollView.

Should use:
    shrinkWrap: true,
    physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),


...
 Widget child = Markdown(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    data: """# **Markdown**
* **First item**
* **Second item**
* **Third item**
""",
  );

